# Rails routing nested views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an admin view, which is from a nested controller, listing out all the conversations from the mailboxer gem see here: ([Mailboxer Gem, Admin View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630044/mailboxer-gem-admin-view/21631970?noredirect=1#21631970)).

I can't get the routing right. The link being created in the admin view goes to /conversations/id, and I need it to go to admin/conversations/id. Both routes when typed into the browser bar work, and show the correct view.

In my controller:

```
 # GET /admin/conversations
  # GET /admin/conversations.json
  def index
    @admin_conversations = Conversation.all.unscoped.order("updated_at desc")
  end

# GET /admin/conversations/1
# GET /admin/conversations/1.json
def show
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
end
```

In my view:

```
<% @admin_conversations.each do |admin_conversation| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= admin_conversation.originator.name %> <span class="label label-default"><%= admin_conversation.originator.role.humanize %></span> </td>
    <td><%= admin_conversation.subject %> </td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(admin_conversation.updated_at) %> ago</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'View Conversation', admin_conversation %></td>

  </tr>
```

The link being created in the view goes to /conversations/id, and I need it to go to admin/conversations/id.

My admin routes:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    resources :managers
    resources :conversations
    get 'enquiries/:status', to: 'enquiries#index', as: :admin_enquiries_with_status, constraints: {status: /(pending|completed|approved)/}
    resources :enquiries, except: [:destroy] do
      post :add_venue, on: :member
      post :remove_venues, on: :member
      post :approve, on: :member
    end
    resources :venues, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
      get :autocomplete, on: :collection
    end
    get "pages/statistics"
  end
```

I've tried working through the rails docs to do with namespace routing but can't seem to get it working. The actual route /admin/conversations/id work's if I type it into the browser bar, and returns the show page from the correct controller. I'm just unsure on what to do to get the link showing correctly?

Conversation controller routes:

```
 send_message POST   /conversations/send_message(.:format)    conversations#send_message
           reply_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/reply(.:format)  conversations#reply
           trash_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/trash(.:format)  conversations#trash
         untrash_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/untrash(.:format)  conversations#untrash
                conversations GET    /conversations(.:format) conversations#index
                              POST   /conversations(.:format) conversations#create
             new_conversation GET    /conversations/new(.:format) conversations#new
                 conversation GET    /conversations/:id(.:format) conversations#show
```

Admin Conversation controller routes:

```
POST   /admin/conversations(.:format) admin/conversations#create
       new_admin_conversation GET    /admin/conversations/new(.:format) admin/conversations#new
      edit_admin_conversation GET    /admin/conversations/:id/edit(.:format)    admin/conversations#edit
           admin_conversation GET    /admin/conversations/:id(.:format) admin/conversations#show
                              PATCH  /admin/conversations/:id(.:format)  admin/conversations#update
                              PUT    /admin/conversations/:id(.:format)  admin/conversations#update
                              DELETE /admin/conversations/:id(.:format)  admin/conversations#destroy
```

Comment: what does `rake routes` tell?

Comment: Updated to show relevant rake routes. Thanks!

Comment: that looks correct to me

Comment: How do I call the correct link then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so worked it out.

```
<td><%= link_to 'View Conversation', [:admin, admin_conversation] %></td>
```

Just had to drop the :admin in and put square brackets around to prepend /admin onto the url.

Should have just read the documentation a bit more thoroughly...